# Granting permanent access for youtube account through Youtube API

Tags: php, youtube

I'm trying to create a smoother video scheduling system for myself to publish my videos on time. The current system uses AutoHotkey to grant access for the script by navigating the account select page. I'd like the script to be able to get access on it's own.

It is written in PHP and uses the Google client library for PHP.

The problem I've encountered is that I can only get permanent access using my main google account (which gets a refresh token), but this account doesn't have access to my youtube account, and can't see private videos.

When I select the youtube account it has access to the videos, but does not get a refresh token, just an access token which expires after 1 hour.

The script is currently using client details from the developer console to get access. I've also tried using a service account, but haven't been able to get it to work.

There the issue there is that I don't know how to impersonate the youtube account, only the main account, which don't have access to the videos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to figure this out. Hidden in the Google Plus settings for my youtube channel account is a "username" for the account.

things@pages.plusgoogle.com

Using this as the impersonation target for the service account allowed it access to the channel, allowing it to publish videos!

I stumbled upon this quite by accident. Nowhere did I find any documentation on how to do this. Bah google.

Comment: Hey @forecaster can you please provide more detail on this? I need to upload video from ios app in my own account without bothering user to do login, so do you have any idea? thanks in advance.

Comment: @Pankaj Do you mean where to find the email address I mentioned?

Comment: Yes please, could you explain where to get that email xxx@pages.plusgoogle.com? I am looking for this right now :)

Comment: @Forecaster yes, and can you please share this example, if you can, that would be really helpful for me.

Comment: @EcoG
(Some of these open new tabs)
1. Go into settings on YouTube
2. Next to your icon and name click "Edit on Google"
3. Close the dialog that appears and go to "Manage Account" in the top right menu
4. Click "View General Account Info"
5. In the middle column (Personal info & Privacy) click "Your personal info"
6. You'll find the email address listed on this page!
I've put screenshots of the things to click in this image and underlined them in red: https://i.imgur.com/ARTACtV.png

Comment: @Pankaj Alternatively you may be able to use the page url to go directly to the page:
https://myaccount.google.com/b/108974731521487766671/email
(Unless it's unique in some way)
(That's a page where just the email is listed, this is the page before it that you end up on if you follow the instructions:
https://myaccount.google.com/b/108974731521487766671/privacy#personalinfo

Comment: Thank you perfect. Now I have to figure out how to login using that email address :D